# Which scope will LocalContentAlpha.current effect when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I run Code A to display the same icon with different color, and Result A is the value of `LocalContentAlpha.current`. I guess the `LocalContentAlpha.current` which locate different position will return different value.

I guess that the `LocalContentAlpha.current` inside `Log.e("my", "Enabled "+LocalContentAlpha.current.toString() )` is the scope of `IconButton`.

Could you tell me if the scope of `LocalContentAlpha.current` inside  `Log.e("my", "Outside "+LocalContentAlpha.current.toString() )` is `Row()` ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun RecordTitleWithToolBar(   
){
     Row() {

        Log.e("my", "Outside "+LocalContentAlpha.current.toString() )

        IconButton(
            enabled = true,
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            DisplayIcon(icon=Icons.Filled.PlayArrow)
            Log.e("my", "Enabled "+LocalContentAlpha.current.toString() )  
        }

        IconButton(
            enabled = false,
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            DisplayIcon(icon=Icons.Filled.PlayArrow)
            Log.e("my", "Disabled "+LocalContentAlpha.current.toString() ) 
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DisplayIcon(
    icon: ImageVector,
    dim:  Dp = 24.dp,
    tint: Color = Color.Blue
) {
    Icon(icon, null, modifier = Modifier.size(dim), tint = tint.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current))
}
```

**Result A**

```
2022-08-28 21:02:59.384 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Enabled 0.87
2022-08-28 21:02:59.387 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Disabled 0.38
2022-08-28 21:02:59.466 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Outside 0.87
2022-08-28 21:02:59.471 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Enabled 0.87
2022-08-28 21:02:59.475 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Disabled 0.38
2022-08-28 21:02:59.480 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Outside 0.87
2022-08-28 21:02:59.485 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Enabled 0.87
2022-08-28 21:02:59.487 26068-26068/info.dodata.soundmeter E/my: Disabled 0.38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find where the `LocalContentAlpha` value comes from by looking into the source code of the composables.

In `IconButton` you can find,

```
val contentAlpha = if (enabled) LocalContentAlpha.current else ContentAlpha.disabled
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentAlpha, content = content)
```

This is the source of `LocalContentAlpha` values in `IconButton`.
In `Row`, we cannot find any such usage of `CompositionLocalProvider`.
So you have to look at the parent composable to see if it provides a `LocalContentAlpha`.

Comment: It seems depricated in new version of Compose